# How to republish latest joystick input

Tags: ros, joy-node, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently the joy node sends a joystick value on update only.  For example if I push the joystick all the way forward I get a single max value of 1.  This value is published only once. A new value is only sent when the joystick moves.  What I would prefer is for the last joy value to keep being published, thus if I push the joystick to its max limit the value of 1 will continue to be published.  Is there something I can add to my joy launch file that will repeat the last received joy message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173503/how-to-republish-latest-joystick-input/) by [Vince Cross](https://answers.ros.org/users/3526/vince-cross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BIRLxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20843/birlxu/) on 2014-11-22**:
Hi,I have the same problem,did you find an answer?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-11-22**:
Did you try the autorepeat?

**Comment by [BIRLxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20843/birlxu/) on 2014-11-22**:
Actually,I am a ROS beginner and I just don't know how to do that.Could you give me some further information?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add

```
~autorepeat_rate = x
```

where x is the rate in Hz that the messages will be sent.  This will constantly publish 0 is there is no value.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matteopantano](https://answers.ros.org/users/29039/matteopantano/) on 2017-09-04**:
For those like me that are struggling, this is a parameter of pkg joy, add it as written here: [joy wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/joy). Thanks Tony!

**Comment by [serhatzengin](https://answers.ros.org/users/46886/serhatzengin/) on 2019-10-22**:
How can I add to my program? Where can I add in my program? How can I control ~autorepeat_rate = x ??

**Comment by [matteopantano](https://answers.ros.org/users/29039/matteopantano/) on 2021-07-13**:
It is in the parameters of your joy node